# Getting MUI's Autocomplete to correctly display categories and subcategories

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to essentially achieve the following image which is found [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/142180/what-is-the-best-way-for-user-to-be-able-to-select-a-category-and-subcategory):

[image: MUI Autocomplete]

In that thread, they talk about the best way to display categories and subcategories and the consensus is an MUI Autocomplete.

I'm not however sure how I would achieve something like that at all and would like some help with how I could achieve it.

What I need is for the user to only be able to select one category, whether it be a "root category" or a sub-category. So in the example above, either the "Boysenberry" or the "Brulee Berry".

I also want to try and have the id of said category so I can apply it on my back end (which I'm sure I can do.

My fetched json structure looks like the below:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Audio Visual Equipment",
        "parent": null,
        "stockItems": [],
        "childCategories": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Projectors",
                "stockItems": [],
                "childCategories": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "Lenses",
                        "stockItems": [],
                        "childCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Lighting Equipment",
        "parent": null,
        "stockItems": [],
        "childCategories": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Intelligent",
                "stockItems": [],
                "childCategories": []
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Generic",
                "stockItems": [],
                "childCategories": []
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "name": "Control",
                "stockItems": [],
                "childCategories": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Sound Equipment",
        "parent": null,
        "stockItems": [],
        "childCategories": [
            {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "Mixing Desk",
                "stockItems": [],
                "childCategories": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Cables",
        "parent": null,
        "stockItems": [],
        "childCategories": [
            {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "Multicore",
                "stockItems": [],
                "childCategories": []
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "name": "Lighting",
                "stockItems": [],
                "childCategories": []
            },
            {
                "id": 13,
                "name": "Audio",
                "stockItems": [],
                "childCategories": []
            },
            {
                "id": 14,
                "name": "Video",
                "stockItems": [],
                "childCategories": []
            },
            {
                "id": 15,
                "name": "Power",
                "stockItems": [],
                "childCategories": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

EDIT:-

I get the following warning when I refresh the page:

```
MUI: The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid.None of the options match with `-1`.You can use the `isOptionEqualToValue` prop to customize the equality test.
```

When I then click on the Autocomplete, I get the "root" categories only. When I then click on one, the name is not shown and I get the following error:

```
MUI: The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid.None of the options match with `1`.You can use the `isOptionEqualToValue` prop to customize the equality test.
```

Comment: Your data seems to have three or more levels of categories hierarchy. May you consider using a tree view instead? https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tree-view/
autocomplete only support 1 level of grouping

Comment: How would I be able to use tree view with what I need as it looks like the examples provided by mui take up quite a bit of space... Ideally I'd like to have just one "box" like Autocomplete to save on space

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### 1. Flattening the List

My approach is to "flatten" the list of categories into a single array so that MUI can evaluate each sub-category.  Each of my flat options has a `depth` property so that I can display it with the correct level of indentation.

We can use the code from the [Checkboxes example](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#checkboxes) and add an indentation with the MUI `sx` prop:

```
renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => (
  <li {...props}>
    <Checkbox checked={selected} sx={{ ml: 2 * option.depth }} />
    {option.name}
  </li>
)}
```

[image]

#### 2. Filtering Matches

I'm assuming that we want to display the top-level category above a sub-category which matches on the sub-category term only. Like in your linked "ber" example, if the category was "Fall Gold" and the subcategory was "Fall Gold Berry".  This means that we should consider the child terms when deciding if a term is a match.

To achieve this, I am including a `matchTerms` property on all option objects and using a custom `filterOptions` function on the `Autocomplete` which looks at this property. With the [`createFilterOptions` utility](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#custom-filter), we just need to determine what texts to examine:

```
filterOptions={(createFilterOptions({
  // join with some arbitrary separator to prevent matches across adjacent terms
  stringify: (option) => option.matchTerms.join("//")
}))}
```

[image]

#### 3. Highlighting

The last piece of this is the highlighting, which is not included in MUI.  The MUI docs recommend the `autosuggest-highlight` package and [include an example](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#highlights) of how to use it.  We can copy that, changing `option.title` to `option.name`.
[image]

### Complete Code

JavaScript

```js
import {
  Autocomplete,
  TextField,
  Checkbox,
  createFilterOptions
} from "@mui/material";
import { data } from "./data";
import parse from "autosuggest-highlight/parse";
import match from "autosuggest-highlight/match";

const toOptions = (category, depth = 0, parentId = null) => {
  const { id, name, childCategories = [] } = category;
  const children = childCategories.flatMap((child) =>
    toOptions(child, depth + 1, id)
  );
  const option = {
    id,
    name,
    depth,
    parentId,
    matchTerms: [name].concat(children.map((obj) => obj.name))
  };
  return [option].concat(children);
};

const optionsList = data.flatMap((category) => toOptions(category));

export default () => {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      options={optionsList}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
      renderOption={(props, option, { selected, inputValue }) => {
        const matches = match(option.name, inputValue);
        const parts = parse(option.name, matches);
        return (
          <li {...props}>
            <Checkbox checked={selected} sx={{ ml: 2 * option.depth }} />
            <div>
              {parts.map((part, index) => (
                <span
                  key={index}
                  style={{
                    fontWeight: part.highlight ? 700 : 400
                  }}
                >
                  {part.text}
                </span>
              ))}
            </div>
          </li>
        );
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      filterOptions={createFilterOptions({
        // join with some arbitrary separator to prevent matches across adjacent terms
        stringify: (option) => option.matchTerms.join("//")
      })}
    />
  );
};
```

TypeScript

```js
import {
  Autocomplete,
  TextField,
  Checkbox,
  createFilterOptions
} from "@mui/material";
import { data } from "./data";
import parse from "autosuggest-highlight/parse";
import match from "autosuggest-highlight/match";

// describes the input data
type Category = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  childCategories?: Category[];
};

// describes the format that we want
interface Option {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  depth: number;
  parentId: number | null;
  matchTerms: string[];
}

const toOptions = (
  category: Category,
  depth: number = 0,
  parentId: number | null = null
): Option[] => {
  const { id, name, childCategories = [] } = category;
  const children = childCategories.flatMap((child) =>
    toOptions(child, depth + 1, id)
  );
  const option = {
    id,
    name,
    depth,
    parentId,
    matchTerms: [name].concat(children.map((obj) => obj.name))
  };
  return [option].concat(children);
};

const optionsList: Option[] = data.flatMap((category) => toOptions(category));

export default () => {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      options={optionsList}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
      renderOption={(props, option, { selected, inputValue }) => {
        const matches = match(option.name, inputValue);
        const parts = parse(option.name, matches);
        return (
          <li {...props}>
            <Checkbox checked={selected} sx={{ ml: 2 * option.depth }} />
            <div>
              {parts.map((part, index) => (
                <span
                  key={index}
                  style={{
                    fontWeight: part.highlight ? 700 : 400
                  }}
                >
                  {part.text}
                </span>
              ))}
            </div>
          </li>
        );
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      filterOptions={createFilterOptions({
        // join with some arbitrary separator to prevent matches across adjacent terms
        stringify: (option) => option.matchTerms.join("//")
      })}
    />
  );
};
```

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-autocomplete-with-hierarchical-data-j4wnpp)